# ASP.NET MVC app as Facebook Fanpage has redirect issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have written a simple HELLO world application which is meant to be used in a Facebook Page (Tab).
Until now everything seems to work fine, the issue which bothers me is the following:

somewhere in a controller action i have code like this:

```
if(condition)
return RedirectToAction(ActionName, ControllerName,...);
```

Supposed the application is hosted on domain   actualdomain.com, then the browser is redirected to:

```
actualdomain.com/ControllerName/ActionName/....
```

to the actual application URI, which is something i don't want: i want the application to stay in the Facebook Tab where it was initiated.

How can i do this?

My app dev environment: VS2010, Facebook C# SDK 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
return new JavascriptRedirectResult(yourAppActionHere);
```

your links should be like 
http://app.facebook.com/testapp/{action name}

Hope it helps